# Remove all items after a specific item in a nested list python

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested, list-comprehension

I have the following nested list and I want to remove all items after ***My Profile*** (including ***My Profile***).

```
my_lst = [['John C, CEO & Co-Funder, ABC company','Eric P, CFO, QWE company','My Profile','Herber W, CTO, PPP company'],
['Eli S, AVP, ACV Company', 'My Profile','Brian M, Analyst, LPL company'],
['Diana F, Managing Director, MS company','Alan X, Associate, JPM company','My Profile', 'Jame R, Manager, AL company']]
```

I tried the coding `[[i for i in nested if i != 'My Profile'] for nested in my_lst]` but can only remove ***My Profile*** from each list.

My expected outputs:

```
[['John C, CEO & Co-Funder, ABC company','Eric P, CFO, QWE company'],
['Eli S, AVP, ACV Company'],
['Diana F, Managing Director, MS company','Alan X, Associate, JPM company']]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) for this task:

```
from itertools import takewhile

my_lst = [['John C, CEO & Co-Funder, ABC company','Eric P, CFO, QWE company','My Profile','Herber W, CTO, PPP company'],
['Eli S, AVP, ACV Company', 'My Profile','Brian M, Analyst, LPL company'],
['Diana F, Managing Director, MS company','Alan X, Associate, JPM company','My Profile', 'Jame R, Manager, AL company']]

out = []
for i in my_lst:
    out.append([*takewhile(lambda k: k!='My Profile', i)])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['John C, CEO & Co-Funder, ABC company', 'Eric P, CFO, QWE company'],
 ['Eli S, AVP, ACV Company'],
 ['Diana F, Managing Director, MS company', 'Alan X, Associate, JPM company']]
```

---

EDIT (list comprehension version):

```
out = [[*takewhile(lambda k: k!='My Profile', i)] for i in my_lst]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension, you could do:

```
my_lst = [['John C, CEO & Co-Funder, ABC company','Eric P, CFO, QWE company','My Profile','Herber W, CTO, PPP company'],
['Eli S, AVP, ACV Company', 'My Profile','Brian M, Analyst, LPL company'],
['Diana F, Managing Director, MS company','Alan X, Associate, JPM company','My Profile', 'Jame R, Manager, AL company']]
results = [nested[:nested.index('My Profile')] if 'My Profile' in nested else nested for nested in my_lst]
```

Without list comprehension:

```
my_lst = [['John C, CEO & Co-Funder, ABC company','Eric P, CFO, QWE company','My Profile','Herber W, CTO, PPP company'],
    ['Eli S, AVP, ACV Company', 'My Profile','Brian M, Analyst, LPL company'],
    ['Diana F, Managing Director, MS company','Alan X, Associate, JPM company','My Profile', 'Jame R, Manager, AL company']]
results = []
for nested in my_lst:
    filtered = nested[:nested.index('My Profile')] if 'My Profile' in nested else nested
    results.append(filtered)
```

Comment: If there's `'My Profile'` in each sublist, this will work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Andrej Kesely, I edited my answer.